Convert Step Function Json to Definition object using Activity
I am new to CDK L2 construct. I am trying to create L2 construct for one of my step function definition. Currently it is in JSON Format want to make it to code. I tried using stepFunction.Activity but it is not taking Resource i.e. arn, Comment, Retry and catch attributes. Can someone help me out on functions usage. Read through the documentation but could not get the right function.
JSON :
{
    "Comment": "random-user-to-role-workflow",
    "StartAt": "Notification Fail",
    "States": {
        "Notification Fail": {
            "Next": "Failure",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:us-india-1:8898762019:activity:Notification",
            "Comment": "Failure Notification",
            "Retry": [
                {
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.ALL"
                    ],
                    "MaxAttempts": 3,
                    "BackoffRate": 2
                }
            ],
            "Catch": [
                {
                    "ResultPath": "$.error",
                    "Next": "Failure",
                    "ErrorEquals": [
                        "States.ALL"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Type": "Task"
        },
        "Success": {
            "Type": "Succeed"
        },
        "Failure": {
            "Type": "Fail"
        }
    }
}


CustomState is what you are probably looking for
It would look something like this:
const successState = new stepfunctions.Succeed(this, "Success");
const failedState = new stepfunctions.Fail(this, "Failure", {
  cause: "Workflow failed",
});

const taskState = new stepfunctions.CustomState(this, "Notification Fail", {
  stateJson: {
    Type: "Task",
    Resource: "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:8898762019:activity:Notification",
    Comment: "Failure Notification",
  },
});
taskState.addRetry({
  errors: ["States.ALL"],
  backoffRate: 2,
  maxAttempts: 3,
});
taskState.addCatch(failedState, {
  errors: ["States.ALL"],
  resultPath: "$.error"
})

const definition = stepfunctions.Chain.start(taskState).next(successState);

Also, since you've defined Success state you probably wanted it to be your next state? Otherwise you would always go to Failed state.
And what is us-india-1? Last time I checked there is no such region.
